# Unable to load ArcGIS Pro Notebook from UNC Path

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-notebook

I am trying to open an ArcGIS Pro Python Notebook I wrote on my remote desktop now that I'm back in the office and somehow my UNC Path is not recognized in my script.  I am able to see the .ipynb file in the file path but ArcGIS Pro is not recognizing it.

How do I re-link the Notebook into my project?

[image]

Comment: yeah this is known problem. One workaround is to add a mapped network drive, and access your .ipynb through it.

Comment: UNC paths now work from notebooks in Pro 3.0 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing issue with loading a *.ipynb file from a UNC path. See this thread: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/cannot-load-a-notebook-from-a-unc-path/m-p/1107759#M46716

Just today I received this error in Pro when adding a Notebook from to a network drive folder:

[image]

Maybe try copying your Notebook file into a local folder then open it in Pro. The work-around I use: Open Pro > Catalog > Add Folder Connection to local folder (i.e. C:) > put *.ipynb file here > Open Notebook